# Redshift of mass-dominant universe

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, redshift

What was the value of redshift $z$ when matter started to dominate the universe?

Is there any way to calculate it without knowing the time?

Comment: $z_{eq} \sim 3000$. It should be easy to calculate if you know the present amount of radiation and matter energy density.

Answer (score 1):

We can calculate the redshift of matter-radiation equality by using the scaling of the energy density of radiation and matter:

$$ \rho_{\text{matter}} = \rho_{\text{matter}}^0(1+z)^3, $$
$$ \rho_{\text{radiation}} = \rho_{\text{radiation}}^0(1+z)^4, $$
where $\rho^0$ denotes the current enegy density.

This gives us
$$ z_{eq} = \frac{\rho_{\text{matter}}^0}{\rho_{\text{radiation}}^0} -1 \sim 3400.$$

The exact current value can be found in [Page 16, Planck 2018 results. VI. Cosmological parameters](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.06209).