# Constraints on the CMB temperature redshift dependence at matter-radiation equality?

Tags: cosmology, cosmic-microwave-background, redshift

As pointed out in the 2011 paper *Constraints on the CMB temperature redshift dependence*... [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1112.1862) the relation between redshift and the CMB temperature, $T_{CMB}(z)=T_0(1+z)^{1-\beta}$ (with $\beta=0$ as base-case) is a key prediction of standard cosmology, but is violated in many non-standard models. In 2011 the constraints were stated as $\beta = 0.004 \pm 0.016$ up to $z \sim 3$

[This](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/215996/redshift-of-mass-dominant-universe) question points out that the *Planck 2018* $z_{eq}$ (matter radiation equality) is $3402 \pm26$. If you apply the CMB Redshift-temperature relation (with $\beta=0$), using the current CMB temperature of $2.725 K$ you get $T_{eq} = 9273 K$, or as an energy density: $\rho_{eq} \approx 0.8eV$.

**However**, as matter and radiation density equality occurs before the CMB was formed, is using the redshift-temperature relation in this way accurate (to the limit of the observational error on $z_{eq}$), or something of an approximation?

**Question: Given the latest observational constraints $z_{eq}$, is $T_{eq}$ and $\rho_{eq}$ similarly constrained?**

Comment: The original question asked what are the observational constraints on $\beta$ at $z_{eq}$. Your edit has totally changed it.

Comment: Apologies @ProfRob, it probably was not worded the best originally. The update has tried to get to the heart of my intent.